# Rails 4: How to put loop logic inside the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have four loops in my haml document for testing purposes with the only difference being the order of the elements.
Am I somehow able to put the logic in my controller and list the whole 'insidyness' of the loop only once in my haml document?
Currently I have everything duplicated 4 times and ya know, that feels bad. :)

For instance:

```
- @loop.where(featured: true).order("RANDOM()").limit(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
- @loop.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
- @loop.order(:impressions_count => :desc).limit(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
- @loop.order("created_at DESC").limit(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
```

Controller:

```
def index
    @loop = Item.all
end
```

I would like to reduce my Haml Code to something like this and move the rest in the Controller:

```
- @loop.each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
```

Thanks in advance for each answer!

Comment: What is `@loop`? what are you exactly trying to do? without understanding the problem we can not help you.

Comment: Sorry, I added that to the answer :)

Comment: Show what you expect.

Comment: You can write the same loop logic in the controller and save it another instance variable and just call that from the haml file. Like inside index def, you can add @loop.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(4).each do |item| @cached_votes_up += item end

Comment: @Bartek Gładys Updated question.

Comment: @tGeek Could you use my example to show that? I am fairly new to rails :)

Comment: Sorry I edited the comment frequently. Have a look.

Comment: @Gugubaight, do you want duplicates in this loop or not ?

Comment: @Bartek Gładys No duplicated items. I just want 4 different loops in a row with different item-order. And all that without writing the haml which belongs into the loop four times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render the view multiple times but you could do something like this.

```
def index
  @loops = [
    Item.where(featured: true).order("RANDOM()"),
    Item.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc),
    Item.order(:impressions_count => :desc),
    Item.order("created_at DESC")
  ]
end
```

And then in the template

```
- @loops.each do |loop|
 - loop.limit(4).each do |item|
   %li
     %h1 This is an example
```

Comment: Just one question regarding this: Will this render everything four times with different orders (as intended), or will this just combine everything to one loop?

Comment: It's two loops. The first loop calls the second loop 4 times (each time with the items in a different order). The second loop renders the html for each item in that loop.

Comment: And where do you init the `loop`-loop?

Comment: Right there in the template. `- @loops.each ...` is looping over the loops. and ` - loop.limit(4).each ...` is looping through each loop.

Answer (score 2):

in `Item` model class:

```
scope :featured_with_random_order_desc, ->(limit_value) { where(featured: true).order("RANDOM()").limit(limit_value) }

scope :by_cached_votes_order_desc, ->(limit_value) { order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(limit_value) }

scope :by_impression_count_order_desc, ->(limit_value) { order(:impressions_count => :desc).limit(limit_value) }

scope :by_created_at_desc, ->(limit_value) { order("created_at DESC").limit(limit_value) }
```

In your views:

```
- @loop.featured_with_random_order_desc(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
- @loop.by_cached_votes_order_desc(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
- @loop.by_impression_count_order_desclimit(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
- @loop.by_created_at_desc.limit(4).each do |item|
    %li
        %h1 This is an example
```

You can go one more step further and create variable for each loop in your controller:

```
def index
  @loop_featured = Item.featured_with_random_order_desc(4)
  @loop_cached_votes = Item.by_cached_votes_order_desc(4)
  @loop_impression_counts = Item.by_impression_count_order_desclimit(4)
  @loop_by_created = Item.by_created_at_desc(4)
end
```

and use them in view:

```
- @loop_featured.each do |item|
  %li
    %h1 This is an example
- @loop_cached_votes.each do |item|
  %li
    %h1 This is an example
- @loop_impression_counts.each do |item|
  %li
    %h1 This is an example
- @loop_by_created.each do |item|
  %li
    %h1 This is an example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union_scope` from `ActiveRecord`

```
    #item.rb

    include ActiveRecord::UnionScope
    scope :by_random, -> { where(featured: true).order("RANDOM()").limit(4) }
    scope :by_cached_votes, ->{ order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).limit(4) }
    scope :by_impression_count, ->{ order(:impressions_count => :desc).limit(4) }
    scope :by_created_at, ->{ order("created_at DESC").limit(4) }

    scope: all_conditions, -> { union_scope(by_random, by_cached_votes,by_impression_count,by_created_at}
```

your controller

```
@item = Item.all_conditions
```

your view:

```
- @loop.all_conditions.each do |item|
```